Equivalence between weak containment and convergence in Fell Topology
We first define Fell Topology. Let $G$ be a topological group and $H$ be a Hilbert space. Let $\hat G$ be the set of equivalence classes of irreducible unitary representations of $G$. We define open neighbourhoods of a representation $(\pi, H)$ as follows: Let $K$ be a compact subset of $G, \epsilon > 0$ and $v \in H$ of norm one. Let $ W(K, \epsilon, v)$ be the set of all  $(\rho,H’) \in \hat G $ such that $ \exists v' \in H'$ of norm one such that $| \langle v, \pi(g)v \rangle - \langle v', \rho(g)v' \rangle | < \epsilon, \forall g \in K  $. These sets form the basis of a topology on $\hat G$ and this is known as the Fell Topology.
Let $(\pi, H)$ and $(\rho, H’)$ be two unitary representations of a topological group $G$. We say that $\pi$ is weakly contained in $\rho$ if for every $\xi \in H$, every compact subset $K$ of $G$, and every $\epsilon > 0$, there exist $\eta_{1}, \eta_{2},.... \eta_{k}$ such that $\forall x \in K$, $|\langle \pi (x) \xi, \xi \rangle - \sum_{i=1}^k \langle \rho (x) \eta_i, \eta_i \rangle| < \epsilon$.
We need to check the fact that a net $(\pi_{i})$ converging to $\pi$ in the Fell Topology is equivalent to the fact that $\pi$ is weakly contained in $\bigoplus_j(\pi_{j})$ for all subnets. Now, $\pi$ is weakly contained in $\bigoplus_j(\pi_{j})$ means that for every $\xi \in H$, every compact subset $K$ of $G$, and every $\epsilon > 0$, there exist $\eta_{1}, \eta_{2},.... \eta_{k}$ such that $\forall x \in K$, $|\langle \pi (x) \xi, \xi \rangle - \sum_{i=1}^k \sum _j \langle \pi_j (x) \eta_i, \eta_i \rangle| < \epsilon$.
I do not know how to show that the conditions are equivalent taking the aforementioned expression forward. The main problem arises when one tries to convert the double sum into a single sum. Is there any theorem that one may apply?
